# Visual Studio 2019 not publishing CSHTML files

Tags: visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I upgraded an MVC5 project a while ago from VS 2013 to VS 2019.  But one (maybe more) of my .cshtml files isn't publishing to the web server.

The file (if relevant) is called: _MainMenuPartial.cshtml

**Build Action**: Content

**Copy to Output Directory**: Do Not Copy

The line in my .csproj states:

```
<Content Include="Views\Shared\_MainMenuPartial.cshtml" />
```

I've also tried adding:

```
<RazorCompileOnBuild>true</RazorCompileOnBuild>
<RazorCompileOnPublish>true</RazorCompileOnPublish>
<CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
```

But no difference.  I've not tried publishing that file on its own yet because I imagine there must be a fix for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Captain_Planet, have you tried excluding from project and including again? And also removing from .csproj, build, add to .csproj and rebuild again? If you try setting _RazorCompileOnPublish_ to _false_, does it change the result?

Comment: Hi.  I've tried all of the above but none worked....

Comment: I think it's fixed now.  I renamed the file on the server to 'xxx.cshtml.old' and published, and it published the updated file.  I then made a change and published again, and the change persisted after the publish.  So perhaps there was some kind of perms/file lock issue with the original file on the server?  Strange,  I just have to hope there isn't a similar issue with other cshtml files, that's the problem (without checking them all after each publish)

Comment: I was wondering if i should check 'Delete all existing files prior to publish' tbh...?

Comment: Glad to hear that! It's very strange, I've never faced something like this before, it could be hard to find the cause. About your question, this could be a possible solution, personally, I often have this option checked on my publishing profiles. You can try the next time you face similar problems, and maybe this helps to clarify the causes. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: One year later, I still see this issue regularly in VS2019.  The {{profile}}.pubxml.user file shows the old date for some .cshtml files and does not publish them, even though the files have a later modified date.  The only fix I've found it to turn on "Delete all existing files prior to publish", which is annoying.